# Python: Write array values into file

Tags: python, arrays, file, append

I'm coding a python project that involves me reading a file and filling an array with the integer values in the file, doing a whole crazy none important process (tic tac toe game) and then at the end, adding a number (wins) to the array and print it back out to the file.

Here's my file reading code:

```
highscores = []
#Read values from file and put them into array
file = open('highscore.txt', 'r') #read from file
file.readline() #read heading line
for line in file:
    highscores.append(file.readline())
file.close() #close file
```

And here's my file writing code:

```
highscores.append(wins)
# Print sorted highscores print to file
file = open('highscore.txt', 'w') #write to file
file.write('Highscores (number of wins out of 10 games):') #write heading line
for i in len(highscores):
    file.write(highscores[i])
file.close() #close file
```

Currently my whole program runs until I read the line: `for i in len(highscores):` in my file writing code.  I get 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

I just want to know if I'm on the right track and how to solve this issue.  I also want to note that these values that I read and write need to be integer types and not string types because I may need to sort the new value into the existing array before writing it back to the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `for` loop will ask i to iterate over the values of an iterable, and you're providing a single `int` instead of an `iterable` object
You should iterate over `range(0,len(highscores))`:

```
for i in (0,len(highscores))
```

or better, iterate directly over the array

```
highscores.append(wins)
# Print sorted highscores print to file
file = open('highscore.txt', 'w') #write to file
file.write('Highscores (number of wins out of 10 games):') 
for line in highscores:
     file.write(line)
file.close() #close file
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, also noticed that I need to say str(line) when write the line in due to my values being ints...  But that's solved so thank you!